# Qual è il senso di "stitico" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nella versione in italiano del monologo *Il primo miracolo di Gesú Bambino* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> E via, ’sta massa di bimbi pigolando come pulcini e ammattiti di festa [impazziti dalla gioia], vanno a impastare e tirano fuori uccelli mai visti! C’è uno che prende un malloppo di creta, improvvisa un gallinone con una gran testa... un pancione... con una codina cosí **stitica** che manco la si vede... poi ci mette una stecca per fare una gamba... un’altra gamba... ma cade in avanti. Un’altra gamba... cade indietro, sul culo!

Ho letto la definizione di "stitico" in parecchi dizionari, ma non mi pare che nessuna delle accezioni che ho trovato abbia senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "codina cosí stitica" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato ***stitico*** indica una cosa piccola e stretta, come da [voce familiare di Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stitico_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/).

Ad esempio:

> In quel ristorante mi hanno servito una porzione di pasta davvero stitica

Comment: Aggiungo che lo Zingarelli, tra le varie accezioni, dà esplicitamente: “2 (fig.) di ciò che è misero, stentato: una prosa stitica”.

Comment: Si usa anche con significato simile: "rachitico"